# Looping through a nodelist JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

My question is : iam trying to get through the NODELIST of class Hot . And i want to change their className  to 'cool' . When iam using the for loop it seems that its the second li doesn't change color. Does anyone know what is my mistake here and the second li element  doesnt change color .

Thank you

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('hot');
var i;

for(i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) { 
  elements[i].className = 'cool';
}
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.hot {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  font-size: 25px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.cool {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
   <div id="page">
      <h1 id="header">List</h1>
      <h2>Buy Greoceries</h2>
      <ul>
         <li id="one" class="hot"><em>Fresh</em>figs</li>
         <li id="two" class="hot">pine nuts</li>
         <li id="three" class="hot">honey</li>
         <li id="four">balsamic vinegear</li>
     </ul>
   </div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is somewhere another styles? for example: for `#two` element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a live node list. Once you've changed the class on one element the node list updates to reflect this so your index will always be out.

One way to mitigate this is to convert the node list to a static node list using `Array.slice.call`:

```
var elements = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('hot'));
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9t271v2b/1/)

Another way, as you point out, is to use `document.querySelectorAll` which returns a static node list:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.hot');
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9t271v2b/2/)

Comment: you are correct . I can use querySelectorAll() which is static right ?