# JavaScript iterate through NodeList

Tags: javascript, loops, nodelist

I am looking for a best way to iterate through NodeList excluding length. I am using:

```
var foo =  document.querySelectorAll('[id^=foo_id]')
console.log(foo)
```

Returned NodeList has all the required elements + the last entry of length:.

```
  0: input#foo_id_...
  1: input#foo_id_...
  ..................
  n: input#foo_id_...
  length: n+1
```

I wonder what the most efficient way to iterate through that NodeList. I can utilize list length etc, but would like to know if there is a more "elegant" way.

Comment: The first line of code in your question is invalid.

Comment: What have you tried? What inefficiencies did you find?

Comment: Also dupe of [Looping through a nodelist JS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35921503/215552).

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The simplest way is a `for` loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
  // Do stuff
}
```

This is the best solution, as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30386316/10221765) it's bad practice to use array methods or convert a NodeList to an array - use a different variable if you need to, but a `for` loop is all you need to loop over a NodeList. (Thanks Heretic Monkey for pointing this out to me).

If you want to use array methods like `forEach`, `map`, etc., it's best convert to an array first - this is incredibly simple with spreading:

```
[...foo].forEach(e /* Do stuff */);
```

If you want to specifically use `map`, use `Array.from` as the second argument is the callback to be applied to `map`.

```
Array.from(foo, e => /* .map callback */);
```

And in older environments:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(foo).forEach(e => /* Do stuff */);
```

<sub>(I know that you can use array methods on a NodeList, but it's easier if you stick to using one data type.)</sub>

Comment: @hereticMonkey but **burgers are better than pizza** (thats just an unjustified claim in bold, not sure where the point is) Also that answer is deprecated, just as this one. There is `NodeList.forEach`, use it.

Comment: You can also use a for...of loop. `for (const el of foo) {...}`

Comment: https://caniuse.com/?search=NodeList.forEach

Answer (score 4):

Although NodeList is not an Array, it is possible to iterate over it with forEach()

See also [Why doesn't nodelist have forEach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433799/why-doesnt-nodelist-have-foreach)

Comment: @neuhas vanilla.js already have inbuilt forEach for nodeList.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList